# How to validate non POST data in Codeigniter 4?

Tags: codeigniter-4

In codeigniter 3, you can validate an array data that is not from $_POST values using the code below:

```
$data = array(
    'username' => 'johndoe',
    'password' => 'mypassword',
    'passconf' => 'mypassword');
$this->form_validation->set_data($data);
```

Is there an equivalent feature in codeigniter 4?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out, we can use it as below:

```
$this->validation =  service('validation');
........

$data = array(
    'email' => 'some_value','address' => 'some_value'
);
$this->validation->setRules(['email'=> 'valid_email']);
if(! $this->validation->run($data)) {
  // not valid
} else {
  // valid
}
```